# Windows CreateThreadpool limit threads count in C++

Tags: windows, threadpool

I use new Thread Pool Windows API in C++ (StartThreadpoolIo/StartThreadpoolIo) in my server to manage IO thread pool (clients are connected via sockets). I have explored MSDN in details but didn't find - how I can limit work threads count?

I can limit work threads for thread pool created via CreateThreadpool (SetThreadpoolThreadMaximum and SetThreadpoolThreadMinimum) but not for CreateThreadpoolIo. Is there function to limit threads count for IO thread pool? Is there the best practice to implement it manually?

Comment: What are you trying to accomplish? `CreateThreadpoolIO` does not create an I/O thread pool. It creates an I/O completion callback for a particular handle. You might start at http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms686760(v=vs.85).aspx, and http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc308561.aspx

Comment: OK, CreateThreadpoolIo creates a new I/O completion object (word by word from MSDN). The thread pool will be created later. It's clear, thanks, Jim. But I still have the same question: is there opportunity to limit threads count in the thread pool? API or manually? If manually then what is the best practice to implement it?

Answer (score 2):

`CreateThreadpool`, then `SetThreadpoolThreadMaximum`, then `InitializeThreadpoolEnvironment` with that pool and call `CreateThreadpoolIo` with that environment. So `IO-callback` will use your limited pool instead of default pool.